# jQuery .attr() with callback behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-lists

Was going through jQuery documentation and found something I don't quite understand, yet )
Let's say on the page I have a list like this:

```
<ul id='list0'>
    <li>list item 1<b></b></li>
    <li>list item 2<b></b></li>
    <li>list item 3<b></b></li>
    <li>list item 4<b></b></li>
</ul>
```

When I run this code

```
$('#list0 li').attr('id', function(i) {
    return (i + 1) % 2 ? 'odd' : 'even';
}).each(function() {
    $('b', this).text(' -> ' + this.id);
});
```

I get output of

- list item 1 **-> odd**
- list item 2 **-> even**
- list item 3 **-> odd**
- list item 4 **-> even**

Everything works as expected and each `<li>` inside of `<ul>` gets an `id` of odd or even.
When I use `each()` to set content inside `<b>` I can get an `id` of `<li>` using  **this.id**.

Question is, why doesn't this work when I use a different `<li>` attribute rather than **id**?

```
$('#list0 li').attr('foo', function(i) {
    return (i + 1) % 2 ? 'odd' : 'even';
}).each(function() {
    $('b', this).text(' -> ' + this.foo);
});
```

Results in

- list item 1 **-> undefined**
- list item 2 **-> undefined**
- list item 3 **-> undefined**
- list item 4 **-> undefined**

Even when **foo** attribute of each `<li>` still sets to even or odd somehow this time I can't get **foo** inside of `each()` with **this.foo**.

I use jQuery 1.10.2.

Thank you.

Comment: is the question retorical or do you have a problem ? If so, let us know what the goal is, as attempting to loop using attributes is not the right tool, think of .attr() as a getter or a setter.

Comment: @RobSedgwick Yes, it's purely rhetorical. I confused node attributes and properties.

Comment: btw the reason why you are able to loop (.each() ) is because jquery returns the initial selection back ( for chaining ). There are no restrictions on getting attributes, but good to use 'data-' for custom ones, ie - ' data-foo="" '

Comment: :) ok, well if retorical, you answer is , not to use .attr() this way, the second param is the setter - it is just evaluating the function you are sending to see if it returns a value to set the attribute as.
consider $("img").attr("src",function() { return "/test.gif"; });

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things to notice here:

First of all `id`s are unique, in practice you should only have one element with a given id at most. So your first code example is something you shouldn't do.

Elements do not have a`foo` [*property*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6003819/properties-and-attributes-in-html), and you need to access it using `this.getAttribute("foo")` or `$(this).attr("foo")`.

So:

```
('#list0 li').attr('foo', function(i) {
    return (i + 1) % 2 ? 'odd' : 'even';
}).each(function() {
    $('b', this).text(' -> ' + this.getAttribute('foo'));
});
```

On a side note - you should probably not have sequential list IDs like `list0, list1` and so on since they prove problematic. You should also consider storing arbitrary data in JavaScript objects and not on the DOM if you were doing that.

Answer (score 1):

> A DOM node may have attributes and properties. But they are really two different things.

for example

using class `Attribute` and className `Property`

For reference

http://javascript.info/tutorial/attributes-and-custom-properties